# PyQGIS: Remove a legend item NOT the whole layer from the project

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, print-composer

I have a number of vector layers and, occasionally, an image basemap.

I am creating a layout programatically based on this data.

I have a legend but I have zero want or need for the basemap raster layer to be displayed. I want to remove the raster item from the Legend, NOT the whole project.

- [PyQGIS - remove layer from legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306615/pyqgis-remove-layer-from-legend)

Answers such as these (and those from years earlier) remove the whole entire layer from the project.

I simply want to remove the legend item. I do however want to keep the raster layer in the project.

This function is called after the layout has been created:

```
def remove_raster_layers_from_legend(project_layers,project,layout_name):
    layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
    layout_def = layout_manager.layoutByName(layout_name)
    legend = layout_def.itemById('Legend')
    root_group = legend.model().rootGroup()  # QgsLayerTree object
    
    legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
    
    for id, layer in project_layers:
        if layer.type().name == 'RasterLayer':
            # Find the legend item corresponding to the layer
            legend_item = root_group.findLayer(layer)
            if legend_item is not None:
                root_group.removeChildNode(legend_item)
    
    legend.adjustBoxSize()
    layout_def.refresh()
```

The inputs are as follows:

```
project = QgsProject.instance() # <class 'qgis._core.QgsProject'>
project_layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().items() # <class 'dict_items'> 
layout_name = "PRINT_LAYOUT_1" # <class 'str'>
```

This is part of a processing script which does some calculations and then styles the layers and creates the print layout.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should consider reconstructing a new legend instead of removing the items from an existing legend. But interestingly, when I use `layout.addLayoutItem(legend)` in a function, QGIS crashes. Therefore, I added a line by line soluiton.

Use this script:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
project_layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().items()
layout_name = "PRINT_LAYOUT_1"

layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = layout_manager.layoutByName(layout_name)

legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
root = QgsLayerTree()

for id, layer in project_layers:
    if layer.type().name != 'RasterLayer':
        root.addLayer(layer)
        print(layer.name())
        
legend.model().setRootGroup(root)    
legend.adjustBoxSize()
legend.setFrameEnabled(True)
legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(0,0, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
```